# Rails 4 Bootstrap3 Dropdown works, then doesn't work

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I put this dropdown on Page A:

```
<span class="dropdown">
  <button id="dLabel" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown trigger
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li>This
    <li>That
  </ul>
</span>
```

... and it works just fine.

When I browse to page B and then browse back to page A, the dropdown is seen on the page, but clicking on the dropdown no longer expands the dropdown window.  It's as if some aspect of javascript no longer works.

The console in developer tools shows no error and the rails server log shows no error.

If I then stay on Page A and reload the page, the dropdown works.  The issue is consistently reproducible.

I am not even sure where to start looking to fix this sort of problem.  If a simple fix is not immediately apparent, how about an approach to narrowing the problem down?  Many thanks.

My application.js file contains this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui/sortable
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require cocoon
//= require steps.js.coffee
//= require protocols.js.coffee
//= require retina-1.1.0.js
//= require ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js
```

UPDATE:

The answer from [luissimo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5768081/luissimo) fixes the above problem.  Clicking on the dropdown now always works.  However, this has uncovered a new issue.  The dropdwon window displays properly.  When I browse to Page B and then back to page A, the dropdown is offset as seen here:

[image]

[image]

Is there a more fundamental root cause to this trouble?

UPDATE:

changing:

```
<span class="dropdown">
```

to:

```
<span class="btn dropdown">
```

... fixed the offset problem.

Comment: Smells like turbolinks issue

Comment: How can I test that?

Comment: If I remove <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %> from application.html.erb, the dropdown is seen on the page, but clicking on the dropdown does not produce the expanded dropdown window.

Comment: like you said when it first render page A dropdown works, but after leaving page A and browsing back to page A dropdown doesnt work aynmore

Comment: you didnt have to remove `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>` since you're already using `//= require jquery.turbolinks`

Comment: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/blob/master/src/turbolinks/compatibility.coffee if go to that link it shows the compatability events with using old events turbolinks < 5 this will enable you to still use `$ ->` in your coffeescripts

Comment: See updated Q.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because Turbolinks causes a page:change event to occur each time a link is clicked and because of that it reevaluates the Javascript every time. Thats why it works at first but when you change pages it might disfunction. This is the easiest work around for it.

```
 <script>
   $('#dLabel').dropdown()
 </script>
```

You can also add `data-turbolinks-eval=false` to the `application.js <script> tag` to interrupt the reevaluation after clicking on links.

Comment: Thanks!  This fixes the problem, but uncovers another.  Clicking on the dropdown now always displays the dropdown window.  Will update my OP to show the subsequent issue.

Comment: Also, can you explain how/why this fixes the problem?

Comment: Added some explanation, hope it helps out!

Comment: Thanks again.  My js is so weak.  What does $('#dLabel').dropdown() do?

Comment: It tells your program that $('#dLabel'), which is the id of the button is actually a dropdown menu (.dropdown() function)

Comment: No problem, glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the order in which you're requiring JS files is not quite right.

From https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks#usage,

You should have the following structure in your `application.js`

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//
// ... your other scripts here ...
//
//= require turbolinks
```

But your mainfest doesn't conform to the requirements of the gem `jquery-turbolinks`. Try changing the order and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for the good advice.  I have updated OP to show my js manifest.

Comment: @PerryHorwich, Updated my answer. Let me know if it solves the issue.